# How to render movie in phaser Canvas background?

Tags: html, video, canvas, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

This seems to work:
http://html5doctor.com/demos/video-canvas-magic/demo1.html

But how can I put the movie into phaser context to play it in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Phaser supports rendering videos. You can find an example [on the phaser examples site](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/loader/load-video).

Answer (score 0):

Create a pixi.textures.VideoTexture and apply the texture to a sprite object.